# Number saved as String in Firestore javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the Vue framework

this is HTML code

```
<input  name="quantity" type="number" v-model="product.price" placeholder="price" >
```

script

```
product: {
        name:String,
        price: null,
      },
addProduct() {
      this.$firestore.Products.add(this.product);
    },
```

[firestore document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSWnH.jpg)

I want to save the price as number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [v-model.number modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number)

```
<input  name="quantity" type="number" v-model.number="product.price" placeholder="price" >
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter data into a text input field in HTML, the value of it becomes a string in the JS code. You need to explicitly convert the actual value into a number. Even though you set the input `type="number"`, that only determines what keyboard mobile users see when they enter the value. It is still a string if accessed via JS

One way to do it:

```
const price = Number(price);
```

[Documentation for Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_to_numbers)

Another method would be to parse it

```
parseFloat(price)
```

Edit: @Beyers' method seems like the best implementation for Vue.

Answer (score 0):

when you capture a form value in javascript, it is by default string. even if you enter a number in the form text field.

```
product: {
    name:String,
    price: null,
},

.......

addProduct() {
    data_firestore = {...this.product};
    data_firestore.price = parseFloat(data_firestore.price)
    this.$firestore.Products.add(data_firestore);
},
```

I am using a spread operator, because, I have no knowledge of , if you are using the **watch** method of **product** object or not. so copying and then modifying seems safer for me. you can do the direct conversion of parseFloat() on the actual object also.